# Can't Run bash file inside ZSH

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, bashrc, oh-my-zsh

I've placed a bash file inside `.zshrc` and tried all different ways to run it every time I open a new terminal window or source `.zshrc` but no luck.

FYI: it was working fine on `.bashrc`

here is `.zshrc` script:

```
#Check if ampps is running
bash ~/ampps_runner.sh & disown
```

Different approach:

```
#Check if ampps is running
sh ~/ampps_runner.sh & disown
```

Another approach:

```
#Check if ampps is running
% ~/ampps_runner.sh & disown
```

All the above approaches didn't work (meaning it supposes to run an app named ampps but it doesn't in zsh.

**Note:** It was working fine before switching to zsh from bash. so it does not have permission or syntax problems.

**Update:** content of ampps_runner.sh:

```
#! /usr/bin/env

echo "########################"
echo "Checking for ampps server to be running:"


check=$(pgrep -f "/usr/local/ampps" )

#[  -z "$check" ] && echo "Empty: Yes" || echo "Empty: No"

if [ -z "$check" ]; then
    echo "It's not running!"
    cd /usr/local/ampps
    echo password | sudo -S ./Ampps
else
    echo "It's running ..."
fi
```

Comment: Is this the whole script? Or do you have a `sha-bang` at the top? i.e. `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @Randomhero it has the sha-bang at the top.

Comment: You are now using a different shell. Not bash. You should try replacing the first line with `#! /usr/bin/env zsh`

Comment: @Randomhero first line of zshrc or ampps_runner.sh ?

Comment: This needs to be the first line of your script. In short, it tells your system which shell to run the script with.

Comment: @Randomhero I've placed #! /usr/bin/env at the top of zshrc and ampps_runner.sh, still nothing happens

Comment: @Randomhero when I run ampps_runner.sh in shell using "bash ampps_runner.sh" it runs but problem is zhrc won't run it.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski it supposes to run an app named ampps. but it does not. no error message.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski no dude, I've updated the question check it out.

Comment: According to : https://serverfault.com/a/98772/547884 and as I need it to run those bashes I had to remove zsh and go back to bash. if anyone has any proper answer please put it here for later use, thanks.